# In what order should the "Cemetery of Forgotten Books" series be read?

Tags: reading-order, spanish-language, carlos-ruiz-zafon, the-cemetery-of-forgotten-books

I have recently ordered the books from [*The Cemetery of Forgotten Books*](https://www.carlosruizzafon.co.uk/the-cemetery-of-forgotten-books/) series. I know that I will be receiving *The Angel's Game* before *The Shadow of The Wind* since *The Angel's Game* was published after *The Shadow of The Wind*, and this makes me think that I should read them in publication order. However, I also know that *The Angel's Game* is a prequel to *The Shadow of The Wind* and sometimes I have found that reading a prequel first can be just as enjoyable.

So, would it be better to read *The Angel's Game* before *The Shadow of The Wind*? Additionally, in what order should *The Cemetery of Forgotten Books* series be read for the most enjoyable experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having now read the series, I would recommend reading the books in the order that they were published because many of the events in the books published later allude to the events of books published earlier.